# Using Environment Variables without any web frameworks

Tags: javascript, variables, environment, api-key

I have been looking for some time for some sort of solution to using environment variables without an attached framework. I'm just creating a simple webpage that displays some information gathered from API web calls. I need a way to hide my API keys, and converting my project to Node JS (to use dotenv or webpack) is overkill. Are there any tools that don't require any additional frameworks. All I need to do is hide some keys.

Anything helps,

Thanks

Comment: If your code is all client-side/in the browser, there's no safe way to protect those API keys without a server in between acting as a proxy to get that data.

Comment: yea ok, that makes sense :c